# Bean Validation and requested parameter in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

Is it possible to use validators for validation request parameters from `javax.validation.constraints` package in any way? I.e. like the following:

```
@Controller
public class test {

    @RequestMapping("/test.htm")
    public String test(@RequestParam("name") @NotNull String name)
    {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this way:

```
public class Comment{

    @NotEmpty
    @Length(max = 140)
    private String text;

    //Methods are omitted.
}
```

Now use @Valid in controller

```
 @Controller
    public class CommentController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/api/comment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        @ResponseBody
        public Comment add(@Valid @RequestBody Comment comment) {
            return comment;
        }
    }
```

When you are applying @Valid for Comment object in your cotroller,it will apply the validation mentioned in Comment class and its attribute  like

```
@NotEmpty
    @Length(max = 140)
    private String text;
```

You can also check this out for little alternate way of doing: 
http://techblogs4u.blogspot.in/2012/09/method-parameter-validation-in-spring-3.html

Comment: How does @Valid know what validator must be invoked?

Comment: Thanks! @Valid annotation is standard java-ee annotation or is exactly  spring?

Comment: Note:
The @Valid annotation is part of the standard JSR-303 Bean Validation API, and is not a Spring-specific construct.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
@Controller
public class test {

    @RequestMapping("/test.htm")
    public String test(@RequestParam(value="name",required=true) String name)
    {
        return "index";
    }
}
```